# Angular Routing: Browser back button doesn't work properly

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a table made in Angular and when I click an item in the table it adds the id to the URL like the following:
`localhost:4200/table` -> `localhost:4200/table/123`
When I then hit the back button in my browser, the browser will reverse the URL to the original state: `localhost:4200/table`.
But the view will not change until I press the browser back button a 2nd time.

I have this code in my `ngOnInit()`:

```
this.router.events.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$)).subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
       //Do stuff
      }
    });
```

I have tried putting logs inside the subscribe function but it does not register the first time browser back button is pressed.

Comment: Can you make a small working example on stackbiz? As I can see so far, you are not changing page component and expecting to reset the state only by some parameter in URL. When you say "the view will not change", do you have any modal windows that you expecting to change the state?

Comment: @Jivopis I have found the issue. The issue for me is that the first page is related to the shell of my app and the new component is loaded as an iframe inside the shell. The solution has been found within this thread: https://ireadyoulearn.info/2022/02/27/advanced-navigation-of-single-page-applications-inside-an-iframe/